# Time not updating in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I'm seriously confused what could be going wrong.

I'm logged into `heroku run console` and trying to update a timestamp on my database.

I've run `User.find(6)` to see that the user has a `:next_click = 2000-01-01...` i don't know why it's that value, but anyway, I do `User.update 6, {:next_click => Time.utc(2015)}` and it seems to update properly saying `2015-01-01 00:00:00`, however when I do another `User.find(6)` it seems the time has switched back because it's not `2015-01-01 00:00:00`.

I'm really confused why it's not. Any insight?

SEE ATTACHED SCREENSHOT[image]

```
irb(main):033:0> User.update 6, {:next_click => Time.utc(2015) }
  User Load (34.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
   (1.8ms)  BEGIN
   (2.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "next_click" = '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000000', "updated_at" = '2012-05-24 00:13:26.197358' WHERE "users"."id" = 6
   (2.2ms)  COMMIT
=> #<User id: 6, name: "mazlix", gold: 10, points: 10, next_click: "2015-01-01 00:00:00", created_at: "2012-05-23 23:40:39", updated_at: "2012-05-24 00:13:26">
irb(main):034:0> User.find(6)
  User Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
=> #<User id: 6, name: "mazlix", gold: 10, points: 10, next_click: "2000-01-01 00:00:00", created_at: "2012-05-23 23:40:39", updated_at: "2012-05-24 00:13:26">
```

The same thing happens with `u = User.find(6)` `u.next_click = Time.utc(2013)` then `u.save`

```
irb(main):001:0> u = User.find(6)
  User Load (38.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
=> #<User id: 6, name: "mazlix", gold: 10, points: 10, next_click: "2000-01-01 00:00:00", created_at: "2012-05-23 23:40:39", updated_at: "2012-05-24 00:57:28">
irb(main):002:0> u.next_click = Time.utc(2013)
=> 2013-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
irb(main):003:0> u
=> #<User id: 6, name: "mazlix", gold: 10, points: 10, next_click: "2013-01-01 00:00:00", created_at: "2012-05-23 23:40:39", updated_at: "2012-05-24 00:57:28">
irb(main):004:0> u.save
   (10.9ms)  BEGIN
   (3.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "next_click" = '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000000', "updated_at" = '2012-05-24 03:05:46.059530' WHERE "users"."id" = 6
   (2.2ms)  COMMIT
=> true
irb(main):005:0> u
=> #<User id: 6, name: "mazlix", gold: 10, points: 10, next_click: "2013-01-01 00:00:00", created_at: "2012-05-23 23:40:39", updated_at: "2012-05-24 03:05:46">
irb(main):006:0> User.find(6)
  User Load (33.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
=> #<User id: 6, name: "mazlix", gold: 10, points: 10, next_click: "2000-01-01 00:00:00", created_at: "2012-05-23 23:40:39", updated_at: "2012-05-24 03:05:46">
```

**`app/models/user.rb:`**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :gold, :name, :next_click, :points
end
```

Comment: The attached screen shot is illegible.  Please copy and paste text in a size that can be read.

Comment: Sorry, I've included the text...

Comment: Could there be a trigger on the table overriding the updates you are making?

Comment: I'm certainly not advanced enough to intentionally do that =p.... I used `rails-api` https://github.com/spastorino/rails-api and did a `rails new scaffold user name, gold:integer, points: integer, next_click: time`... if that helps any...

Comment: What happens if you `u = User.find(6); u.next_click = ...; u.save`?

Comment: A trigger like that doesn't happen by accident; it sounds as if 'trigger' is not the explanation.

Comment: @muistooshort .. the same thing :(....... I updated the question

Comment: What does your `User` model look like? Any hooks?

Comment: What's weird about this is that the updated_at column changes Oo. I'd do it like this `User.find(6).update_attribute(:next_click, Time.utc(2015))` but I'm not sure if it will make a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've created a time column. Slightly confusingly, even though in ruby `Time` stores time + date, in the database world the concept of a pure time of day (ie just hours/minutes/seconds) exists and that's what you get when you add a column of type :time to your migration.

Ruby itself doesn't have a class that represents a time without a date so rails uses an instance of `Time` but ignores the date bit.

If you want a column that stores both time and date, change the column to a :datetime one (you'll still get a `Time` instance back in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

In your ActiveRecord can use the data type `:timestamp` or `:datetime` to store the correct date format.